# How do I merge XML from distinct DomDocuments

Tags: .net, xml

What is the easiest way to merge XML from two distinct DOM Documents?  Is there a way other than using the Canonical [DataReader](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311530) approach and then messing with the outputted DOM.  What I basically want is to AppendChild to XmlElements without getting: `The node to be inserted is from a different document context.`  Here is C# code that I want to work, that obviously won't (what I am doing is merging two documents which have bunch of nodes that I am interested in parts of):

```
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
doc1.LoadXml("<a><items><item1/><item2/><item3/></items></a>");
XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
doc2.LoadXml("<b><items><item4/><item5/><item6/></items></b>");

XmlNode doc2Node = doc2.SelectSingleNode("/b/items");

XmlNodeList doc1Nodes = doc1.SelectNodes("/a/items/*");

foreach (XmlNode doc1Node in doc1Nodes)
{
    doc2Node.AppendChild(doc1Node);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the XmlDocument.ImportNode method to copy a node from a XmlDocument to another.

Comment: Note that when you .ImportNode() you get a new node. Use that one - the old one will still throw an exception!

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode.aspx. But take a close look at the "The following table describes the specific behavior for each XmlNodeType."-part of that document.